# Show that the subspace $(a, b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic with $(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the subspace $(a, b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic with $(0, 1)$

In this question (taken form *Munkres*), is $(0, 1)$ referring to the following subspace $\left((0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}\ , \  \mathcal{T} = \{(0, 1) \cap U \ | \ U \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}\}\right)$?

Comment: I'd suggest proving that $x \to x-a$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.  Similarly I would then show that $x \to \frac{x}{b-a}$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.  The restriction of the composition of these maps is a homeomorphism from $(a,b)$ to $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(0,1)$ refers to the subset $(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology.  In general, subsets of "standard" spaces (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$) are commonly assumed to have the subspace topology unless stated otherwise.